# How to use css in one page only?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have 5 menus let it be: Menu1, Menu2, Menu3, Menu4, Menu5. I have header in `header.php` and footer in `footer.php`. I want to use a date picker in a single menu only i.e menu3.

To include my date picker in one page i.e under menu3, I include following links in my header.

```
 <head>
   <link href="styles/glDatePicker.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <script src="glDatePicker.min.js"></script>
```

Now I want to ask that, how to include `glDatePicker.default.css` and `glDatePicker.min.js`in menu3 only. Because I don't want to include them in other pages.

Any ideas??

Please Help

Comment: get your current page by using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], and if it contains menu3 then include glDatePicker.default.css and glDatePicker.min.js otherwise not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can try detect a pattern in the url with php:

> PHP

```
<? if(strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], $pattern_that_you_detect_in_url) !== false){ ?>
  <link href="styles/glDatePicker.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<? } ?>
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Can't we have default way to do so ? bcoz ur code is not a default. Its not wrong, if i dnt want to check the condition what should i do. I dn.t want to check the condition every time the page loads

Comment: @yank If your page loads the same header.php in all pages, you only can do this. If you write a final part of your header.php and a example for page I can see if you can do this with other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], 'menu3.php') !== false)
{
 echo "<link href="styles/glDatePicker.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">";
 }
```

you will need to change your if statement so it suits your setup. But this is the easiest way i can think of. Just put this PHP script in your header.

For more info about  $_SERVER array, see the [PHP manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for it

Comment: wrong answer, it should be if(strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], 'menu3.php'))